# SMS Testing tool

Tags: stress-testing

What tool can I use that will allow me to send 100 sms messages (from 100 different sample users) at the same time to one number.
I am trying to test my site which will show a number users can text to win a prize and I want to test it to see how it will handle about 100 users at once.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you building an app that sends/receives SMS? Or, are you just wanting to stress test receiving SMS on a personal number? Seems like if you're building an app and using a service like Twilio, they'd have ways to test this. Otherwise, I think it would be hard to find a service to do just a one-off test as spammers could use that for any purpose.

Comment: Have a look at the IntelliSMS API.